# What is the java equivilant to MySQL's smallint

Tags: java, mysql

I have a column in a MySQL table called`dead_heat_flag` which data type is `smallint`, 
and I want to represent this column as one attribute in my Java class. 
What data type should I use?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a `short`?

Comment: Also you could have just google "Java primitive data types" and you would have your answer much more faster than asking the question here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I think there's a section in the JLS about dead heats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the comment below, for [MySQL's smallint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html), java's `short` should cover that value range. Of course, you could also use an `int`, but keep in mind that it allows many values that the database column does not.

Comment: mysql database is  integer ok for it

Answer (score 3):

I believe the datatype equivalent would be a `short` based on what I found [here for java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [here for a db that uses smallint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html).  They both address the same range of values.

Answer (score 2):

Short in java is equivalent to small int as there range is same.It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive).

Refer this
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for java
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/gcmaz/ for database

Comment: It depends on the database behind. If you read the page you linked, you'd see that it could also be another type that boolean.